# Pegar classe CSS de outros sites usando PHP HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, css, dom, id

To tentando pegar uma classe de um site de notícias, mas não estou conseguindo.

```
$titulo = $html->find('feed-post-body-title gui-color-primary gui-color-hover', 0)
               ->innertext;

echo $titulo;
```

Ta dando esse erro:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Como faço pra conseguir pegar classes ou ids?

Comment: Amigo, a variável `$html` está recebendo o que exatamente?

Comment: $html = file_get_html('url_do_site');

Comment: Ta recebendo a url do site que eu quero pegar a classe

Comment: Amigo, tente como este exemplo

`foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';`

No entanto, talvez seu retorno do file_get_html está dando erro, ou a variável `$html` está como array, tem que buscar saber como é exatamente o retorno da função e em que estado ou qual conteúdo existe dentro da variável.

Comment: Pegar os objetos normais HTML eu consigo... O problema ta sendo pegar algum objeto com determinado ID ou Class css

Comment: Olha a resposta dessa dúvida http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761115/find-div-with-class-using-php-simple-html-dom-parser acho que é exatamente isso que você deve fazer.

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Ajudou bastante!

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa especificar o elemento que está procurando, se é uma **div**, um  **p** e etc...

Se fosse uma div por exemplo, ficaria assim:

//Usando o "." (ponto) para especificar que é uma classe

```
$titulo = $html->find('div.feed-post-body-title', 0);
```

ou

```
$titulo = $html->find('div[class=feed-post-body-title]', 0);
```

//Se você estivesse procurando por um elemento com id no lugar da classe:

//Usando  "#"  para especificar que é um id

```
$titulo = $html->find('div#feed-post-body-title', 0);
```

ou

```
$titulo = $html->find('div[id=feed-post-body-title]', 0);
```